# How to find the date for the upcoming weekend in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, date

so I wanted to have an option called Weekend Delivery, but I can't seem to find any nifty Date#method that can help determine the date (like 2011-09-24) for Saturday, say.

So far I come up with:

```
today = Date.today
sat = today + (6-today.wday) # 6 being the 6th day of the week with 1 being Monday
```

Not that it's not short enough, but I thought if there are any built-in or Gem method that does something like Date.this_sat, Date.this_thur, Date.this_weekend, it would be nice..

Thanks!

Comment: The activesupport method might be better than the one I suggested if you are doing this in rails. I suggested the option I did because you had this flagged as ruby not rubyonrails :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Chronic gem](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic/), it is fantastic!

```
gem install chronic
```

Here is an example:

```
require 'chronic'
Chronic.parse('this Saturday noon')
#=> Sat Sep 24 12:00:00 PDT 2011
```

I edited the output to reflect the newest gem version since I am using an older version.

Comment: Agreed! Stuff like this is why I love ruby.

Answer (score 3):

Well, ActiveSupport has an [end_of_week](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Date/Calculations.html#M000281) method. Subtract 1 and you're there: weekend!